Does Convergence in Distribution imply convergence in Kolmogorov distance?
I am aware of the result that, Convergence in Kolmogorov distance implies that in pointwise distributional convergence. The converse is not generally true unless the limiting distribution is absolutely continuous.
I am curious to know whether any other stringent conditions for limiting distribution can be imposed if we don't have absolute continuity of limiting distribution function and still this converse result holds true!
Thanks in advance.
